# How to add line which runs through origin (from positive to negative) on a scatterplot - highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a reference line that runs through the origin and passes from negative to positive. See an example of what i am trying to achieve - see the threshold line. This threshold line must run through all three x, y coordinates (-1,-45,000), (0.0), (1, 45,000).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLK80.png)

Below is my work so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/catio6/rhf6yre5/1/

I've looked at this for reference but have had had no luck after several hours of attempts of replicating this with all three x, y coordinates (-1,-45,000), (0.0), (1, 45,000): http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/XvjfL/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 256]
        }]

    }, function(chart) { // on complete
         console.log("chart = ");
        console.log(chart);
        //chart.renderer.path(['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 100, 200, 50, 300, 100])
        chart.renderer.path(['M', 75, 223.5,'L', 259, 47])//M 75 223.5 L 593 223.5
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'red'
            })
            .add();

    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to try to draw an asymptote using the SVG path function. The asymtote would not respect Highcharts axis scaling (unless you dinamycally calculate it, of course). Couldn't you just build another series based on a function that would draw the line as a "line" chart? You would even get more information about the asymptote when hovering... If that's an option, I can help you with that...

Comment: Ok, i'm getting closer, but how do i make the lines go to infinity without including additional datapoints on the spline chart? Thanks for your help btw http://jsfiddle.net/catio6/bn1f00xo/5/

Comment: Hi @Rolo_Sher, did you check my answer below?

Comment: I did @JoãoMenighin but the problem i now have is when i try download as an image the axes become distorted. Any idea how i can resolve? Really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: That's another different issue. It seems like a bug, actually. It seems to have something to do with the `offset` property in your `yAxis`. I would suggest you to open an issue on [Highcharts Github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts) and/or another question here

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help @JoãoMenighin I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @Rolo_Sher, you are welcome. If my answer below is enough for you, would you mind marking it as the right answer? Just click the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Highcharts doesn't have, as far as I know, a way to define a line that goes from/to infinity.
One idea I had to solve this issue for you is dynamically calculate the values for the line series based on your data. The idea is simple: Given the maximum values for X and Y you want to plot, we just need to limit the axis to a certain value that makes sense and calculate the values for the asymptote series in order to make it seems infinite. My algorithm looks like this:

```
// Get all your other data in a well formated way
let yourData = [
 {x: 0.57, y: 72484},
 {x: 0.57, y: 10000}
];

// Find which are the maximum x and y values
let maxX = yourData.reduce((max, v) => max > v.x ? max : v.x, -999999999);
let maxY = yourData.reduce((max, v) => max > v.y ? max : v.y, -999999999);

// Now you will limit you X and Y axis to a value that makes sense due the maximum values
// Here I will limit it to 10K above or lower on Y and 2 above or lower on X
let maxXAxis = maxX + 2;
let minXAxis = - (maxX + 2);
let maxYAxis = maxY + 10000;
let minYAxis = -(maxY + 10000);

// Now you need to calculate the values for the Willingness to pay series
let fn = (x) => 45000 * x; // This is the function that defines the Willingness to pay line

// Calculate the series values
let willingnessSeries = [];
for(let i = Math.floor(minXAxis); i <= Math.ceil(maxXAxis); i++) {
    willingnessSeries.push([i, fn(i)]);
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n5xg1970/

I tested with several values for your data and all of them seem to be working ok.
Hope it helps
Regards